# Преобразовать код в фото

Tags: php, instagram

Работаю с Api инстаграма. Нужно получить список фото пользователя. В ответ на запрос получаю код. Как преобразовать его в фотографии?

Comment: Минуту подождите, я позвоню ванге, и уточню какой вы получаете код :) только не уходите

Comment: Местный заместитель ванги, посовещавшись с КО, говорит, что инстаграмовское api [отдаёт json][1].


  [1]: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

Answer (score 1):

Делаете запрос на

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=
```

В ответе получаете ответ в json формате, парсите его через

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

Вуаля, в $data у вас ответ сервера, там и ссылки на фото, и кол-во лайков, и комментарии итд... Инфа по методу тут [вот тут](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)